# Multiple Entry into Korea

Tags: visas, south-korea

I’m planning a trip to Korea and I am an Indian citizen. Now as an Indian, I can visit Jeju (by virtue of it being a Special Administrative Province) without a visa but for the rest of Korea I need a visa. My question is that if I go from Busan to Jeju then back to Busan, does that count as entering Korea twice? I’m asking because the fee for a single entry visa for less than 90 days is significantly cheaper than a multiple entry visa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it's a single entry. Jeju is part of South Korea, so a visa valid for South Korea is valid for Jeju as well.